# Get specific div after finding a checked radio button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a couple of radio buttons on a page (about 30 or so), some of the radio buttons have events that toggles a div (show/hide).
I'm trying to make it possible that, when the form is being edited (with data from database), if a radio button is selected, it's related div should be shown without a click.

Code I have tried and example html

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">        
    <div>
        <input type="radio" value="yes">Yes
        <label>
        <input checked="checked"  type="radio" value="No">No</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">       
    <div class="col-xs-3 input-group">
        <input id="buttonToHideThis" onclick="showDiv(this, showThis)" checked="checked" type="radio" value="yes">Yes
        <input onclick="showDiv(this, hideThis)" type="radio" value="no">No
    </div>
</div>

<div class="showThis" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form-group">            
        <div class="col-lg-3 input-group">
            <input id="test" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var $rButtons = $('input[type="radio"]');

$.each($rButtons, function () {
    var value = $(this).attr('value');

    if($(this).is(':checked') && value == 'yes'){
       $(this).closest('div').css('background-color', 'green');
    }
});
```

I have problems getting div "*showThis*" to show when "*buttonToHideThis*" is checked on document ready. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through just checked buttons

```
var checked_button = $('input[type="radio"]:checked');
checked_button.each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'yes'){
       $(this).closest('div').css('background-color', 'green');
    }else{
       $(this).closest('div').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/9tb452fw/2/)

Comment: Your solution is the same as what I tried already. Using that method only changes the div around the radio button itself. I'm trying to change the a div two or three levels below.. The div with class "showThis".

Comment: @Makten you should provide the full html structure .. to let us know the relation between div contain radio buttons and div you target

Comment: @Makten http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/9tb452fw/4/  Is this your structure?? if yes this is a demo .. if not please update the Jsfiddle with your code

Comment: your jsfiddle example is similar to my html structure

Comment: @Makten so the js code in jsfiddle should work with you

Comment: Your jsfiddle gave me the right direction. Got it working now.. Thanx for the help.